# Check if constructors of subclass are public in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, metaprogramming

Hope this is not duplicated, but wasn't able to find an elegant solution. Is it possible to say that subclasses of a special base class can only created in a template factory function? Because of simplicity I only want to force this behavior in the base class. Here is an simple example:

```
template <class T>
T* createBase();

template<typename T>
class Base {
protected:
    template <class T>
    friend T* createBase();

    static T* create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
};

class TestClass1 : public Base<TestClass1>
{
public:
    TestClass1() : Base() {}
};

template <class T>
T* createBase()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base<T>, T>::value, "use the createBase function only for Base<T> subclasses");
    return Base<T>::create();
}
```

Actually this is allowed:

```
TestClass2 *testClass = createBase<TestClass2>();
TestClass2 tester;
```

But I only want to have this:

```
TestClass1 *testClass = createBase<TestClass1>(); //allowed
TestClass1 tester; // compile error
```

For sure I know I only have to put the constructor of TestClass1 `private` or `protected`. But it would be really nice to say that in the Base object.

**Edit:**

An compile error when the constructor of the subclass is public would be a also a nice solution. Maybe with a static_assert().

Comment: Sure I can do this but I wat to force this behavior in the Base<T> class. The User shouldn't be able to create an Object of type Base<T> without the factory method. So how can i force the User to set the Constructor private or protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the accessibility of a constructor from the base class, even with CRTP.

What you can do is add a static_assert in the base ctor checking that the `T` a.k.a the derived class has no publicly accessible default ctor:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value,
                      "T must not be default constructible");
    }
};
```

the `static_asswert` doesn't work on class scope for reasons showned here: [CRTP std::is_default_constructible not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34924432/2805305)

Comment: idk, I completely retarded, can't make the `static_assert` to work. I'll be back after I clear my head.

Comment: Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f2d664520cb1fa0)? I'm guessing you tried the `static_assert` just in the class scope, which doesn't work for reasons I'm not entirely sure of. Maybe related to the `friend` declaration.

Comment: @TartanLlama I tried in the ctor like you as well, after it didn't work at class level. Got confused because I kept old code, it looked like that didn't work as well.

Comment: There is on think which confuses me too. When I put the ctor of the TestClass1 private or protected. How can I make my object accesible for the function createBase<TestClass2>();?

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924432/crtp-stdis-default-constructible-not-working-on-template-parameter-with