# CRTP std::is_default_constructible not working as expected

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits, crtp

```
template <class T>
class Base {
     static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value,
                   "T must not be default constructible");
};

struct X1 : Base<X1> {};
struct X2 : Base<X2> {
   X2() = default;
};
struct X3 : Base<X3> {
   X3() {};
};
struct X4 : Base<X4> {
   X4() : Base{} {};
};

struct Y1 {};

int main() {
    // all compile. They shouldn't
    X1 x1; X2 x2; X3 x3; X4 x4; 
    // all compile. They shouldn't:
    Base<X1> bx1; Base<X2> bx2; Base<X3> bx3; Base<X4> bx4;  

    Base<Y1> by1; // static assert fires. This is the expected behavior
}
```

The `static_assert` at class level doesn't fire for any of the `X` classes. But kicks in for `Y` (which doesn't derive `Base`)

It works correctly if the `static_assert` is moved inside the constructor of `Base`

What is the reason that `is_default_constructible<T>` is always false at class level if `T` derives from `Base`?

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/KIZh3Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Base<X1>` is instantiated in the inheritance list of `X1`, `X1` is an incomplete type. This means that `X1` is not default-constructible when the class-scope `static_assert` is checked.

The constructor for `Base` is only instantiated upon use, at which point `X1` is now a complete type and is default-constructible. This is why the `static_assert` fires when inside the constructor, but not at class-scope.

Answer (score 0):

As per [TartanLlama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924692/2805305), `T` is incomplete at class level when `T` is `X`.

I want to add this results in **Undefined Behavior** as `T` must be a complete type for `is_default_constructible`:

[cppreference docs for is_default_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible):

> T shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array
>   of unknown bound. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.